# Simple example of an explicit Henkin sentence?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, formal-languages

I came across the concept of explicit Henkin sentences in a discussion of Gödel sentences, but I'm unable to find a concrete example of an explicit Henkin sentence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, some background. Recall that the Goedel sentence asserts its own unprovability. We could also ask about sentences which assert their own *provability*, a much weirder situation. While [Kreisel showed](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2268627?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that the situation is more complicated for "pathological" provability predicates, [Lob's theorem](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~laskow/Pubs/713/Lob.pdf) famously states that (among other things) every sentence expressing its own provability in a "reasonable" way is in fact provable! And such sentences are called *Henkin sentences*.

So a Henkin sentence asserts its own provability. An *explicit Henkin sentence* goes one step further: it tells you *how* it is proved.

*The formal definition of an explicit Henkin sentence is as follows: an explicit Henkin sentence is one of the form "$t$ is a proof of me," where $t$ is some closed primitive recursive term.*

For example, the following is an explicit Henkin sentence:

> $0$ is the Goedel number of a proof of this sentence.

This is *false*, and easily disprovable, since $0$ isn't the Goedel number of *any* proof. So explicit Henkin sentences are meaningfully different from Henkin sentences.

OK, what about *true* (indeed, provable) explicit Henkin sentences? It's not at all clear that these exist, but it turns out that they do; and this was [proved by Solovay](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2273791.pdf). The proof is short, but uses a standard diagonal lemma approach, and such arguments provide very very messy example sentences (although they do provide examples when appropriately unwound - they are constructive, just not efficiently so).  So if you ask, "What's a simple example of a **true** explicit Henkin sentence?", then Solovay's proof does not provide a satisfying answer, and indeed I'm not aware of any simple example.